# why does Spring STS 3.8.2 not moving forward in installation?

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite, ubuntu-16.04

I did update  **ubuntu 14.04 LTS** to **16.04 LTS** and I tried to change the version of **Spring STS** to the newest version **STS 3.8.2**.
  But while the demanding the workspace folder **"/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.2.RELEASE "** and I press "OK" , it gives me an error:

[image: a busy cat]

in the file ( this file is automatically deleted if I if I close the error msg) :

```
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:490)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:504)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:203)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:626)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-ea/Method.java:535)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)

 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
... 23 more

 Caused by:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-ea/ClassLoader.java:419)
... 25 more
```

it seems  Eclipse Neon M7 for Java EE developers (STS based on it) doesn t work with latest oracle jdk 9 build

Comment: And have you done as the message indicates...

Comment: yes but I  didn't find the file that it talks about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Neon M7 for Java EE developers (STS based on it) doesn t work with latest oracle jdk 9 build. 
that's the problem 
changing the oracle jdk version to an oldest one  solve the problem
in my case  I used the oracle jdk 8  to solve things